# DocumentDB vs Cosmos DB - Are both same?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I was using DocumentDB for the product and now I hear that there's no DocumentDB! There's this new Cosmos DB which Microsoft is building which is superset of DocumentDB. I'm really confused now.

Is it only the name they changed or there are many more changes?
Can someone shed a light on this?

Comment: Just read the announcement - google "cosmosdb inroduction" - it's all there. Explains the new features, the renaming, etc.